# What is the Design Class property of a file in a project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In Delphi XE2 if I select a file in the Project Manager the Object Inspector shows the properties of the file. What is the "Design Class" property for and how is it used?

Answer (score 0):

"Design Class" is a read only property. It shows the classname of the derived object. I've only seen this property set on a TFrame.